# Reset Express static directory dynamically

Tags: node.js, express

I want to reset the express static directory while the server is running. I implemented it by using an application-level middleware.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
        if (someCondition) {
           srcDir = path.join(someDir, someVariablePath);
           app.use(express.static(srcDir));

           return res.sendFile(path.join(srcDir, 'index.html'));
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
```

Is this implementation is correct or can someone guide me a correct way of resetting the static directory

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why do you need to dynamically change a directory for static files?

Comment: Need to handle the application updates, For each update, static dir should be reset

Comment: What do you mean by 'application updates' and why the dir should be reset? What happens if it's not reset?

Comment: I have a separate web application. The web application updates are pushed dynamically. Need to reset the static directory when an update is available, If not new changes are no available

Comment: If you mean that files in this static dir are changed then you don't need to reset anything, express will serve files from the dir and will pick the latest version of the file each time. If you mean that you app's files are changed then you'll have to restart your express server for changes to apply

Answer (score 0):

i replaced

```
app.use(express.static('build/'))
```

with

```
app.use('*', express.static('build/'))
```

and it works without any issues

Comment: You mean replacing app.use(express.static('build/')) with app.use('*', express.static('build/'))?

Comment: yes, but make sure you handle other routes before this function